# Is there any solution can send message to a group of user (not all user) using spring4 websocket?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Recently, I use spring4 websocket to push message to end user.

I known that, there are 2 methods (`convertAndSend`, `convertAndSendToUser`) to send message in class **SimpMessageSendingOperations**  .

But is there any way to send message to a group of user, and the user out of group cannot subscribe the message?

Thank you very much.

Comment: quick question: why users should not subscribe to a particular topic?

Comment: Yes, they can subscribe different topic with corresponding group, but I want to know how to protect the topic from user who is not in the group to subscribe THIS topic. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. Hope someone can answer!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Spring Framework 4.0.x, it is possible to send messages to a group of users by:

- explicitly sending messages to each user, using a for loop
- sending messages to a particular topic, given those users subscribed to this topic beforehand.

As you mentioned, you don't want users that don't belong to that "group" to be able to subscribe to this topic. This calls, in fact, for authorization features.

With 4.0.x, security features are implemented at the HTTP level, for example during the HTTP Upgrade phase, before clients switch to websocket (see [the websocket-portfolio application](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio)).

The feature you're asking for is implemented in Spring Security 4.0.0 (to be released, [see this blog post for a full preview](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/preview-spring-security-websocket-support)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read [this](http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/) article, and I have try the way of ApplicationEvent. But I cannot capture SessionConnectEvent, SessionConnectedEvent or SessionDisconnectEvent, when client connected, is this a bug?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. However, there is a method to use BrokerAvailabilityEvent ([reference](http://kimrudolph.de/blog/spring-4-websockets-tutorial/)). I tried using this in my application and this event is captured normally.