# Spring 4 Websocket support and a client subscribing to all topics

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I am currently looking at using the new Websocket support in Spring to replace a custom  server built on top of Netty. One of the things that I am having a problem with is getting spring to only send messages to a single user (based on a session).

During this testing it also appears that a websocket client, once authenticated, can subscribe to "/queue/*/*" and get messages for other users. We are using the spring websocket client in an Eclipse RCP app to connect to the spring server.

Am I missing something here or are we just trying to use it in a way that is not intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [user destinations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination) and the [@SendToUser annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/annotation/SendToUser.html)?

Comment: Hi, that will certainly send a message to that user, but I have found that you can intercept all other user specific messages for other users by basically subscribing to the root queue.. like session.subscribe ("/queue/*/*")

Comment: Is there any way to disallow certain subscription types?

Comment: Do you want to [secure an endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012270/is-there-any-solution-can-send-message-to-a-group-of-user-not-all-user-using-s/23092950#23092950)?

Comment: That looks to be the goods. At first we just want to ensure that a connected STOMP client cannot subscribe to the root queue and get other people's messages, and I should be able to do this by looking at that app.